# Clip and draw images on canvas and on mouse down drag images in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I can clip images using drawImage and display it in canvas method, but i don't know how to change the position of the particular clipped image on mousemove ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just attach the image's x and y position to the current mouse x and y.

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

    /// correct mouse position so its relative to canvas
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}
```

Just replace the simple form of `drawImage()` here with the one using clipping. If you meant you want to draw the image *inside* the clip region use x and y for source x and y instead (and also remember to check that x and y are inside image dimension in that case - you can also use a `clip()`'ed path in this case).

**[Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7LhQn/)**